# Count of unique columns based on another row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

If you have the following table:

```
ID, item
1, A
2, A
1, A
1, B
3, C
```

I would like to get these results

```
ID, A, B, C
1, 2, 1, 0
2, 1, 0, 0
3, 0, 0, 1
```

There should be a column for each item type. In a perfect world, I would not need to get these item types ahead of time.

Is there a way to do this with a SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

You might use conditional aggregation by *sum()* function :

```
select ID,
       sum(case when item = 'A' then 1 else 0 end ) as a,
       sum(case when item = 'B' then 1 else 0 end ) as b,
       sum(case when item = 'C' then 1 else 0 end ) as c
  from items
group by ID
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/KDZ10853)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing the items up front?

Comment: Or a better way if there are thousands of entries of item?

Comment: @MatthewKnippen sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a pivot function.  Redshift does not currently support those.

If you are passing the SQL results to something else (like [python](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), or [excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576%22excel%22), or [Chartio](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-pivot-table-with-redshift-or-postgres/)) there are easy follow-up steps to pivot.  But in Redshift, you have to manually do the sum function mentioned above.